# Formatting a String in to add '\'' before and after every word

Tags: python

I want to pass a list of words the function bellow. And have the out put as follows:

```
  \'word1\' || ' ' || \' word2 \' || ' ' ||  \'word3 \' || ' ' ||  \'word4 \'
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
def format_words(*words):    
  s = "\\' ".join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in words)
```

But it the output does not match the expected output. how can I improve the function above to get the output that I desire.?

Comment: What's the problem with this code? What's the question?

Comment: The question is fine, not sure why this was closed. I was typing up an answer but it was closed lol

Comment: @sleepystar96 I have submitted the question for review.  Hopefully it will be opened again.

Comment: I should've just sent the code in the comments, sorry for the delay. https://replit.com/@SleepyStar/formattingstringwithslash#main.py lmk what you think

Comment: *"But it the output does not match the expected output."* - add to question the "wrong" output that you got.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but you have two problems:

1. Your input list of words has inconsistent spacing. For example, near `word1\` there is no space before the slash, but at `word3 \` there is a slash. These inconsistencies can mess up your join.
2. Your `.join` tries to do too much and would be missing the starting and ending `\\'` as well as the  `|| ' ' ||` that separates each word.

Consider the following code for the fix:

```
def format_words(words):
  s = "\\'" # add the first backslash, quote
  s += "\\' || ' ' || \\'".join(words) # join all the words with this separator in the middle
  s += "\\'" # add the last backslack, quote
  return s
  
formatted = format_words(["word1","word2","word3","word4"])

print(formatted)

expectedOutput = "\\'word1\\' || ' ' || \\'word2\\' || ' ' || \\'word3\\' || ' ' || \\'word4\\'"
print(expectedOutput)
assert formatted == expectedOutput
```